# Initiate Microsoft Teams calls using different application with deep linking

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to initiate MS Teams calls as part of a mobile app. While planning to develop this feature, I explored documentation that was available and it is suggesting to register with the bot to implement this feature.
We wanted confirmation on whether this is the only way or there is an alternate way so as to achieve deep linking of Call feature with MS Teams?